# My external HD corrupted after forced reboot

Tags: usb, hard-disk, devices, data-recovery, corruption

After update kernel, I forced reboot and canceling jobs what running in shutdown.

The external hard drive is corrupted and does not display in /dev.

Relevant information in log:

```
[sda] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)

[sda] 2:0:0:0: [sda] 0-byte physical blocks

[sda] 2:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is on
```

Apparently, I lost the first section of the disc.

When I plug HD:

```
$ date; lsusb
Thu Oct 14 01:11:49 PM -03 2021
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 0bc2:2312 Seagate RSS LLC Expansion <-- HERE MY HD
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0408:a031 Quanta Computer, Inc. VGA WebCam
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04d9:a070 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. USB Gaming Mouse
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0aaa Intel Corp. Bluetooth 9460/9560 Jefferson Peak (JfP)
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

$ date; lsusb
Thu Oct 14 01:12:10 PM -03 2021
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0408:a031 Quanta Computer, Inc. VGA WebCam
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04d9:a070 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. USB Gaming Mouse
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0aaa Intel Corp. Bluetooth 9460/9560 Jefferson Peak (JfP)
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**journalctl log:**

```
# journalctl -xe
Oct 14 15:41:51 localhost.localdomain kernel: usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
Oct 14 15:41:51 localhost.localdomain kernel: usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=2312, bcdDevice= 6.37
Oct 14 15:41:51 localhost.localdomain kernel: usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Oct 14 15:41:51 localhost.localdomain kernel: usb 2-1: Product: Expansion
Oct 14 15:41:51 localhost.localdomain kernel: usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Seagate 
Oct 14 15:41:51 localhost.localdomain kernel: usb 2-1: SerialNumber: NA4A5TDJ
Oct 14 15:41:51 localhost.localdomain kernel: scsi host2: uas
Oct 14 15:41:51 localhost.localdomain kernel: scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  Expansion        0637 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
Oct 14 15:41:51 localhost.localdomain kernel: sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
Oct 14 15:41:51 localhost.localdomain mtp-probe[7363]: checking bus 2, device 9: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1"
Oct 14 15:41:51 localhost.localdomain mtp-probe[7363]: bus: 2, device: 9 was not an MTP device
Oct 14 15:41:51 localhost.localdomain mtp-probe[7366]: checking bus 2, device 9: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1"
Oct 14 15:41:51 localhost.localdomain mtp-probe[7366]: bus: 2, device: 9 was not an MTP device
Oct 14 15:41:51 localhost.localdomain kernel: sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Spinning up disk...
Oct 14 15:42:18 localhost.localdomain kernel: ....................
Oct 14 15:42:18 localhost.localdomain kernel: usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 9
Oct 14 15:42:18 localhost.localdomain kernel: ready
Oct 14 15:42:18 localhost.localdomain kernel: sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Oct 14 15:42:18 localhost.localdomain kernel: sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Sense not available.
Oct 14 15:42:18 localhost.localdomain kernel: sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Oct 14 15:42:18 localhost.localdomain kernel: sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Sense not available.
Oct 14 15:42:18 localhost.localdomain kernel: sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
Oct 14 15:42:18 localhost.localdomain kernel: sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] 0-byte physical blocks
Oct 14 15:42:18 localhost.localdomain kernel: sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is on
Oct 14 15:42:18 localhost.localdomain kernel: sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 00 ff 00
Oct 14 15:42:18 localhost.localdomain kernel: sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Asking for cache data failed
Oct 14 15:42:18 localhost.localdomain kernel: sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
Oct 14 15:42:18 localhost.localdomain kernel: sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Oct 14 15:42:18 localhost.localdomain kernel: sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Sense not available.
Oct 14 15:42:18 localhost.localdomain kernel: sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Oct 14 15:42:18 localhost.localdomain kernel: sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Sense not available.
Oct 14 15:42:18 localhost.localdomain kernel: sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
Oct 14 15:42:18 localhost.localdomain systemd-udevd[7388]: sda: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-block-scheduler.rules:6 Failed to write ATTR{/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/block/sda/queue/scheduler}, ignoring: No such file or directory
```

**udevadm log:**

```
$ udevadm monitor 
monitor will print the received events for:
UDEV - the event which udev sends out after rule processing
KERNEL - the kernel uevent

KERNEL[2490.193806] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1 (usb)
KERNEL[2490.206879] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[2490.208975] add      /devices/virtual/workqueue/scsi_tmf_2 (workqueue)
KERNEL[2490.209654] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/host2 (scsi)
KERNEL[2490.209694] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/host2/scsi_host/host2 (scsi_host)
KERNEL[2490.209737] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[2490.209785] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1 (usb)
KERNEL[2490.212831] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/host2/target2:0:0 (scsi)
KERNEL[2490.212871] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0 (scsi)
KERNEL[2490.212924] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/scsi_device/2:0:0:0 (scsi_device)
KERNEL[2490.212969] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/scsi_disk/2:0:0:0 (scsi_disk)
KERNEL[2490.213089] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/scsi_generic/sg0 (scsi_generic)
KERNEL[2490.213266] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/bsg/2:0:0:0 (bsg)
UDEV  [2490.219539] add      /devices/virtual/workqueue/scsi_tmf_2 (workqueue)
UDEV  [2490.220932] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1 (usb)
UDEV  [2490.224142] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [2490.225548] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/host2 (scsi)
UDEV  [2490.227328] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/host2/scsi_host/host2 (scsi_host)
UDEV  [2490.229401] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [2490.237204] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1 (usb)
UDEV  [2490.238676] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/host2/target2:0:0 (scsi)
UDEV  [2490.240380] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0 (scsi)
UDEV  [2490.241713] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/scsi_device/2:0:0:0 (scsi_device)
UDEV  [2490.241790] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/scsi_disk/2:0:0:0 (scsi_disk)
UDEV  [2490.244685] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/bsg/2:0:0:0 (bsg)
UDEV  [2490.245127] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/scsi_generic/sg0 (scsi_generic)
KERNEL[2516.543460] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/bsg/2:0:0:0 (bsg)
KERNEL[2516.543596] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/scsi_generic/sg0 (scsi_generic)
KERNEL[2516.543636] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/scsi_device/2:0:0:0 (scsi_device)
UDEV  [2516.551973] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/scsi_generic/sg0 (scsi_generic)
UDEV  [2516.552038] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/bsg/2:0:0:0 (bsg)
UDEV  [2516.552079] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/scsi_device/2:0:0:0 (scsi_device)
KERNEL[2516.558252] add      /devices/virtual/bdi/8:0 (bdi)
KERNEL[2516.558477] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/block/sda (block)
KERNEL[2516.559087] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0 (scsi)
KERNEL[2516.559208] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/scsi_disk/2:0:0:0 (scsi_disk)
KERNEL[2516.559364] remove   /devices/virtual/bdi/8:0 (bdi)
KERNEL[2516.559530] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/block/sda (block)
UDEV  [2516.560180] add      /devices/virtual/bdi/8:0 (bdi)
UDEV  [2516.560857] remove   /devices/virtual/bdi/8:0 (bdi)
KERNEL[2516.571257] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0 (scsi)
KERNEL[2516.571313] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0 (scsi)
UDEV  [2516.575310] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/block/sda (block)
UDEV  [2516.577021] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0 (scsi)
UDEV  [2516.578044] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/scsi_disk/2:0:0:0 (scsi_disk)
UDEV  [2516.578571] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/block/sda (block)
UDEV  [2516.579974] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0 (scsi)
UDEV  [2516.580855] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0 (scsi)
KERNEL[2516.585385] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/host2/target2:0:0 (scsi)
KERNEL[2516.585487] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/host2/scsi_host/host2 (scsi_host)
KERNEL[2516.585517] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/host2 (scsi)
UDEV  [2516.586557] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/host2/target2:0:0 (scsi)
UDEV  [2516.586607] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/host2/scsi_host/host2 (scsi_host)
UDEV  [2516.587461] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/host2 (scsi)
KERNEL[2516.596286] remove   /devices/virtual/workqueue/scsi_tmf_2 (workqueue)
KERNEL[2516.596433] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[2516.596463] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[2516.596914] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1 (usb)
KERNEL[2516.596952] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1 (usb)
UDEV  [2516.597223] remove   /devices/virtual/workqueue/scsi_tmf_2 (workqueue)
UDEV  [2516.597820] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [2516.598843] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [2516.601267] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1 (usb)
UDEV  [2516.602571] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1 (usb)
```

Answer (score 0):

After to send my device to assistance, they identified physical damage in the head seek. Thanks!